# In Traditional Development, What Percentage Time is Spent on Analysis?

Tags: analysis, sdlc

I recall hearing some numbers related to the percentage time that is spent on analysis in a traditional software project. However, I'm now looking for references and coming up short. The only thing I have found so far refers to the Mythical Man Month where it states that 1/3rd of a project is spent on Planning. But I'm now looking for a more up-to-date reference. Does anyone have any other references from well known sources? TIA.

Answer (score 3):

Nice question. The distribution of labour for software development across labour types varies per project, project approach and organisation. It has challenged me quite a lot in the past as an R&D manager. For current project we always work with some kind of FPA and in our case 15% for analysis unless reasons to deviate.

But that's not your question. Regarding references I've found most help in that period of my life with [CMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability_Maturity_Model_Integration) (Capability Maturity Model, nowadays CMMi) and advice from Hans Sassenburg (nowadays living in CH). CMM induces that most organisations can not reliably predict the amount of analysis needed for a project till the variables influencing analysis time across the project have been brought into control. This includes also staffing ("replace the senior analyst by a junior which makes a lot of mistakes") and procedures ("waterfall" or "agile").

A nice quote from [this presentation](http://www.se-cure.ch/images/SBO%20-%20Description.pdf) on predicting effort is ”You can’t fix 
what you refuse to measure”. This [article on software cost prediction](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.9824&rep=rep1&type=pdf) gives some more information.

Summarizing: either take a reasonable gamble based upon historical projects or ensure your projects, teams and customers are similar and more accurately calculate the amount of analysis time.

Answer (score 3):

1) International Software Benchmarking Standards Group (ISBSG, http://www.isbsg.org/) collects this data, you can buy their report.

2) There also used to be (still is?) Chinese Software Benchmarking Standards Group (CSBSG) that collected this data for Chinese projects. I believe I saw their data some years ago, but I can't find it anymore, and their site www.csbsg.org is no longer up. I still see reference to them as a part of ISBSG at http://www.totalmetrics.com/function-points-groups/csbsg, for example.

3) I was able to find this report at COCOMO Forum'08 http://www.docstoc.com/docs/20160200/Phase-Distribution-of-Software-Development-Effort that compares CSBSG data with COCOMO II distribution - see slide 14 there. Acc to it, the Planning and Requirements phase is slightly above 15% for CSBSG, and slightly above 5% for COCOMO. Design phase takes another 15% acc to CSBSG and 35% acc to COCOMO model.

4) I also found another paper http://www.compaid.com/caiinternet/ezine/Reifer-Benchmarks.pdf (2004) that provides effort/duration distribution figures. In particular, the Plans and Requirements phase for waterfall is ~7% (2..15%) in terms of effort, 16-24% (2..30%) in terms of duration. Design phase is extra 17%  / 24-28%. There are also distributions acc to other methodologies provided inside.

Comment: This is just the sort of thing I was after. Thanks!